# boot ends in purple screen

Tags: boot, kernel

I'm in Ubuntu 16.04.
After booting it get stacked in an all purple screen. If booting in recovery mode I get these messages

VFS: Cannot open root device "mapper/ubuntu--vg-root" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
Please append a correct "root+" boot option; here are the available partitions:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.13.0-45-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu
Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 3521/0010T1, BIOS A14 07/31/2015
Call trace:
 dump_stack+0x63/0x8b
 panic+0xe4/0x24d
 mount_block_root+0x1fd/0x2ac
 mount_root+0x38/0x3a
 prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x194
 kernel_init_freeable+0x212/0x23b
 ? rest_init+0xc0/0xc0
 kernel_init+0xe/0x101
 ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Kernel Offset: 0x3d000000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff8000000-0xffffffbffffff)
--[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it . Purple/ black same fix

Comment: Second that error is because the root partition can not be found. Boot a live usb and run boot repair

Comment: Booring from live usb says "Booting kernel failed: Invalid argument"

Comment: Did you checksum the iso?